# Flask Python has just started adding random hash .dpbs to url

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask python site that I inherited, just serving up static pages, and yesterday I added a new route and the live site (hosted on heroku) has started appending these weird hashes to the end of my uri's in the address bar:

example:

- previously: `http://example.com/login`
- now: `http://example.com/login#sthash.ZKhHFDgv.dpbs`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this relate to any cookies? Possibly CSRF protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an identifier appended by third-party share bars to let them track when someone shares a URL with someone else.

For more information, see here: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/517332-share-widget-faqs#copynshare.

Comment: That's the one - thanks so much Jimmy! All fixed now ( :